# C++: Setting precision to a variable, not only for couting

Tags: c++, precision

I have a self made stack and I'm writing a method push() for it. I am pushing one number to the stack, sometimes it's int and sometimes it's double. When it's double, I've got another variable saying what precision it should have (how many numbers after coma).

**Let's say I've got variables d = 7,39518 and prec = 3, can I somehow set precision of d to value of prec so the outcome is that value of d = 7,395?**

*I know how to do it for couting, but how to change the actual variable?*

Comment: You can not set the precision of the double.

Comment: The precision of floating-point values is determined by how they are implemented. You do not have any control over that, other than selecting `float`, `double`, or `long double`. When you **display** a floating-point value you can control the precision of the **text** that gets shown, but that does not affect the floating-point value.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: I've got feeling this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (quite common for newbies). I recommend you to refreeze your question and describe what your application should do, what end user should see. After that put your stack into a picture. Maybe you do not have to store precision in stack, maybe stack doesn't have to have variant functionality. Maybe we misunderstood why you need fixed precision.

Comment: @MarekR I explained bellow what my purpose is.

Comment: bellow you have written `thing is about traits`. This prove my point and people misunderstood your problem. We need more context of the problem, for now I'm voting to close question as it is not clear what is the topic.

Comment: You can't change the precision of `double` nor any other built in type. You can manipulate the representation only.

Answer (score 3):

Neither the core language nor the standard library offers such a type.

In other languages and libraries it's known as a *decimal* type, and more in general, e.g. in computer science, as a *fixed point* type. E.g. C# has an 128-bit `decimal` type, and the Windows API offers a 64-bit `DECIMAL` type (part of the OLE Automation set of types). Essentially a value consists of a signed integer for the digits, and either a small integer specifying the number of decimals, or knowledge of such a value specified at compile time.

You can easily implement such a type yourself, but the Boost library offers [`cpp_dec_float`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/high_precision/use_multiprecision.html#math_toolkit.high_precision.use_multiprecision.using_boost_multiprecision_cpp_f).

---

For more general info about floating point, google up what every scientist should know about floating point.